# Can this javascript be shortened? Jquery is an option

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is when each select field is changed, it will pass part of the directory needed for the form action (the value of each option). ie:

```
<select onChange="chgFrmAtn" id="1-1">
 <option value="">Any</option>
 <option value="exDir1Option1">option 1</option>
 <option value="exDir1Option2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

So here is the javascript, basically I want to build 2 directories, several different options. The number of options is much longer than the list in this example script. The options can be in any order. if any is selected, it doesn't add to the directory.

```
function chgFrmAtn( itemVal )
{
    var directory1Part1 = '';
    var directory1Part2 = '';
    var directory1Part3 = '';

    var directory2Part1 = '';
    var directory2Part2 = '';

    if(itemVal == '1-1'){
        directory1Part1 = document.getElementById(itemVal);
    }
    if(itemVal == '1-2'){
        directory1Part2 = document.getElementById(itemVal);
    }
    if(itemVal == '1-3'){
        directory1Part3 = document.getElementById(itemVal);
    }
    if(itemVal == '2-1'){
        directory1Part1 = document.getElementById(itemVal);
    }
    if(itemVal == '2-2'){
        directory1Part2 = document.getElementById(itemVal);
    }
    document.advancedSearchForm.action = directory1Part1 + directory1Part2 + directory1Part3 + '/' + directory2Part1 + directory2Part2 + '/';
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to use loops. Use arrays or objects instead of multiple variables. No, jQuery doesn't help much here.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
function chgFrmAtn(itemVal)
{
      document.advancedSearchForm.action = document.getElementById(itemVal).value;
}
```

basically you will only get one value in your `directoryxParty` since itemVal will remain same and only one if statement will true.

**Edit:**

If it has to append values from each select, then

var selectIds = ["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-2"];

```
function chgFrmAtn()
{
     var vals = selectIds.map(function(id){ 
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        return obj && obj.value ? obj.value : ""; 
     }); 
     document.advancedSearchForm.action = vals[0] + vals[1] + vals[2] + '/' + vals[3] + vals[4] + '/';
}
```

Comment: It needs to build the action out of all fields selected though. Will this work to apend each value? and remove if an option is changed back to "any"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two array and map the comparison.

```
function chgFrmAtn(itemVal) {
    var vals = ['1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '2-1', '2-2'],
        directory = vals.map(function (a) {
            return itemVal === a ? document.getElementById(a) : '';
        });

    document.advancedSearchForm.action = directory[0] + directory[1] + directory[2] + '/' + directory[3] + directory[4] + '/';
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is a much cleaner solution. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @nico, more levels -> new design.

Comment: Hey Nina, how would I change it so directory[0] is giving directory[0].value ? currently I would need to add .value after each array item in the action change.